# Optimize a query for calcilating datetime difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table:

```
+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| id      | party_id | begintime           | endtime             | to_meas |
+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 1395035 |     9255 | 2010-09-26 00:34:02 | 2010-09-26 03:56:20 |       0 |
| 1395036 |     8974 | 2009-07-10 11:00:00 | 2009-07-10 21:30:00 |       0 |
| 1395037 |     8974 | 2009-07-10 23:14:00 | 2009-07-11 08:48:00 |       0 |
| 1395038 |     8975 | 2009-07-10 11:00:00 | 2009-07-10 21:30:00 |       0 |
| 1395039 |     8975 | 2009-07-10 23:14:00 | 2009-07-11 08:48:00 |       0 |
| 1395040 |     8974 | 2009-07-11 10:08:31 | 2009-07-12 18:49:51 |       0 |
| 1395041 |     8975 | 2009-07-11 10:08:31 | 2009-07-12 18:49:51 |       0 |
| 1395042 |     8974 | 2009-07-12 20:38:27 | 2009-07-13 20:33:21 |       0 |
| 1395043 |     8975 | 2009-07-12 20:38:27 | 2009-07-13 20:33:21 |       0 |
| 1395044 |     8974 | 2009-07-13 21:57:37 | 2009-07-15 08:25:45 |       0 |
| 1395045 |     8975 | 2009-07-13 21:57:37 | 2009-07-15 08:25:45 |       0 |
| 1395046 |     8974 | 2009-07-15 08:51:25 | 2009-07-16 10:29:13 |       0 |
| 1395047 |     8975 | 2009-07-15 08:51:25 | 2009-07-16 10:29:13 |       0 |
| 1395048 |     8974 | 2009-07-16 12:22:22 | 2009-07-17 14:39:10 |       0 |
| 1395049 |     8975 | 2009-07-16 12:22:22 | 2009-07-17 14:39:10 |       0 |
| 1395050 |     8976 | 2009-07-24 16:53:48 | 2009-07-25 08:47:29 |       0 |
| 1395051 |     8977 | 2009-07-24 16:53:48 | 2009-07-25 08:47:29 |       0 |
| 1395052 |     8978 | 2009-07-24 16:53:48 | 2009-07-25 08:47:29 |       0 |
| 1395053 |     8979 | 2009-07-24 16:53:48 | 2009-07-25 08:47:29 |       0 |
| 1395054 |     8976 | 2009-07-25 10:47:14 | 2009-07-26 09:41:44 |       0 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
...
```

I need to calculate time between `begintime` and previous `endtime` and set `to_meas` to 1 if this difference is > 30 minutes. Here is my attempt to do it in MySQL:

```
update doses d set to_meas=1 where d.id in 
  (select a.id from party join (select * from doses) a 
  on party_id=a.party_id 
  left join (select * from doses) b 
  on party.id=b.party_id 
  and b.begintime=(select min(begintime) 
  from (select * from doses) c 
  where c.begintime > a.endtime) 
  and timestampdiff(minute, a.endtime, b.begintime) > 30 
  group by party.id);
```

This command runs (quasi-) forever. I've tried to do it in python's `pandas`:

```
conn = engine.connect()
sql =
    '''
    select doses.id, party_id, party.ml, begintime, endtime
    from doses join party on party.id=doses.party_id
'''
df = pd.read_sql(con=conn, sql=sql,
measure = df.groupby('party_id', as_index=False).apply(
    lambda x: x[pd.to_datetime(x['begintime']) - 
    pd.to_datetime(x.shift()['endtime']) > pd.to_timedelta('30 minutes')])
measure_ids = measure['id'].to_list()
measure_list = ','.join([str(x) for x in measure_ids])
conn.execute(
    'update doses set to_meas=true where id in(%s)' % measure_list)
```

The last statement runs about 10 seconds. Is there a way to optimize SQL code for running as fast as the `pandas`` one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can get `select` the result you want with window functions, like so:

```
select d.*,
    (begintime > lag(endtime) over(partition by pary_id order by endtime) + interval 30 minute) as to_meas
from doses d
```

In earlier versions:

```
select d.*,
    (
        begintime > (
            select max(endtime) + interval 30 minute
            from doses d1
            where d1.party_id = d.party_id and d1.endtime < d.endtime
        )
    ) as to_meas
from doses d
```

I would not recommend storing such derived information. You can use the query, or create a view. But if you really insist on an `update`:

```
update doses d
inner join (
    select id,
        (
            begintime > (
                select max(endtime) + interval 30 minute
                from doses d1
                where d1.party_id = d.party_id and d1.endtime < d.endtime
            )
        ) as to_meas
    from doses d
) d1 on d1.id = d.id
set d.to_meas = d1.to_meas
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your data using exists as follows:

```
Update doses d
   Set meas = 1
 Where begintime > (select max(dd.endtime) + interval '30' minute 
From doses dd where dd.begintime < d.begintime
  And dd.party_id = d.party_id)
```

Comment: MySQL does not support reopening the target table of an update statement in a correlated subquery, so this query raises a syntax error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd80c71a7cc6bb8b98c181fd864d6821. That's a typical limitation of MySQL's `update` syntax.

Comment: @GMB here it should be like I did: `... From (select * from doses) dd ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the data, you can use window functions in the `update`:

```
update doses d join
       (select d.*, 
              lag(d.endtime) over (partition by d.party_id order by d.endtime) as prev_endtime
        from doses d
       ) dd
       on d.id = dd.id and
          d.starttime > dd.prev_endtime + interval 30 minute
    set to_meas = 1;
```

Then, for this query, you want an index on `doses(party_id, endtime)`.  I assume that `id` is already declared as a primary key.

Note:  With this index, you might find it faster simply to calculate the value on the fly rather than storing it in the table.

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, you can phrase this as:

```
update doses d join
       (select d.*, 
               (select d2.endtime
                from doses d2
                where d2.party_id = d.party_id and
                      d2.endtime < d.endtime
               ) as prev_endtime
        from doses d
       ) dd
       on d.id = dd.id and
          d.starttime > dd.prev_endtime + interval 30 minute
    set to_meas = 1;
```

You have relatively few rows per `party_id` so a correlated query seems reasonable.  This also needs an index on `(party_id, endtime)`.

Comment: The OP commented at some point on my answer they were running MySQL 5.7. That comment was removed though.

Comment: Yes, I have 5.7